Terraform: How to write x3 Nested for loop (DRY)
Hello and sorry for the naive question - I've been banging my head trying to get this one right and not repeating myself.
I need an array of metrics containing arrays of string as per AWS dashboard metrics:
Currently I have metrics defined as such:
local.keys is a List of Strings
      metrics = [
        for i, k in local.keys : [
          for metric in ["metric1", "metric2"] : [
            for method in ["method1", "method2"] : [
              "Server", metric, "dim1", k, "dim2", method,
              { "region" : "...", "id" : "ms${method}${i}", "visible" : false }
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]

Wanting the output to be like:
[["Server", metric, "dim1", k, "dim2", method,{ "region" : "...", "id" : "ms${method}${i}","visible" : false }] ... ... ...]

but it is not.

Figured out how and what:
locals {
  metrics = flatten([
    for i, k in ["Comp1", "Comp2"] : concat([
      for metric in ["metric1", "metric2"] : [
        for method in ["GET", "POST"] : {
          entry = [
            [
              "NameSpace", metric, "Dim1", k, "DIm2", method,
              {
                "id" : "${metric == "metric1" ? "ms" : "m"}${method}${i}",
                "visible" : false
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
      ], [{ "expr" : [{
        "expression" : "100*((msGET${i} + msPOST${i} + msOPTION${i} + msPUT${i} + msUPDATE${i} + msPATCH${i} + msTRACE${i} + msCONNECT${i} + msDELETE${i})/(mGET${i} + mPOST${i} + mOPTION${i} + mPUT${i} + mUPDATE${i} + mPATCH${i} + mTRACE${i} + mCONNECT${i} + mDELETE${i}))",
        "label" : k,
        "id" : "exp${i}"
    }] }])
  ])
  x = [for x in local.metrics : contains(keys(x), "entry") ? x.entry : x.expr]
}

This way I am getting all the metric entries; plus the expression metrics needed for each company.
